# How to use TextFormField Inside Listview.builder so that each TextFormField have different controller value

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, textformfield

I'm getting data from API with price and name price should inside text form field allowing the user to update price and publish data. but the issue is when I'm going to publish with the new price it is showing to the next element after publishing Successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use form widget and define a form a key and use listview as child of the form widget. then use onSaved:() and insert the value to a list inside TextFormField.then give a sumbit button and give _fromkey.currentstate.save() inside on pressed like this`

```
Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Column(children: [

            Container(
                    child: Column(
                        children: [
                          TextFormField(
                            onSaved: (String value){//add value to a list},

                     ),
              
                   ),
                 ),
                   ElevatedButton(
            
                         onPressed: () {
                             _formKey.currentState.save();
                  
                         },
                         child: Text('Submit'),
                       )
                   ),
                 )
```